# Rewrite from local path to external domain - C# MVC IIS 7.5 URL

Tags: c#, iis, model-view-controller, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I'm having trouble getting url rewriting working in an MVC app in that I need to direct all requests from 
https://www.thisdomain.com/assets/* to their equivalent at https://www.thatdomain.com/assets/* e.g

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/app.css">
```

loads in the resources from https://www.thatdomain.com/assets/css/app.css

I've currently got this in the web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="Map Assets" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="assets/(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.otherdomain.com/assets/$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

and added this into my RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("assets/");
```

Url Rewrite is installed on the server.

Any help would gladly be appreciated.

Comment: A variation of mistake 1 in https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0):

Some questions:
Those "www.thisdomain.com" and "www.otherdomain.com", are hosted on the same server? 
Are you sure you want "Rewrite", not "Redirect"?

I am not even sure that it's possible to *rewrite* to another domain.
You can rewrite a resource path or name, but domain makes not much sense to me. 
But Redirect could be configured as follows:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="Map Assets" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="assets/(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.thisdomain.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="www.otherdomain.com/assets/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```